# How does fast-forward merge resolve in these two cases?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm pretty new to git and was thinking about how merging is handled based on what I read in the docs and on blogs. In general, it's been a source of a lot of confusion for me. I'm simply interested in the base case of fast-forward merging. So here's what I know, or at least think I know.

1. Git fetch  downloads data and updates remote tracking branches, but doesn't integrate changes to working tree
2. Git merge  will merge the specified branch *into* the current checked-out branch.
3. Git pull   is a combination of these procedures. Fetch the remote and merge the specified branch into the current branch.

The key idea here which is confusing me is that git merge (alone or as a part of git pull) merges the specified branch *into* the current branch.

So I looked at a few diagrams for fast-forward merging and I'm wondering about the following 2 cases.

1. Let's say that my current branch is 4 commits ahead of the remote branch that I want to pull.

o---o---o---o---o
^remote            ^current

then my understanding is that pulling remote into current will just fast-forward the remote pointer to the current HEAD. We'll be left with:
o---o---o---o---o
                          ^current & remote

2. Let's say that my current branch is 4 commits behind the remote branch that I want to pull.

o---o---o---o---o
^current            ^remote

then what happens? Doesn't remote get pulled *into* current all the same?
Does this collapse the history to:

o
^current & remote

Is my picture of the diagram wrong?
Can someone explain what happens in both these cases and resolve my confusion? Thanks.

Comment: 1. No, pulling remote into current will do nothing since remote is not ahead of current, which I assume is local. 2. Here, **pulling** from the remote into current will move current up to the same place as remote. As for 3, "collapse history", not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: In order to affect the remote pointer you have to push. In order to affect the local pointer (related to a remote) you do a pull or a merge (pull is equivalent to a fetch + a merge).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Wow, okay I was very misguided. That makes a lot of sense! Thanks +1 Does that mean the statement that git merge branchName merges branchName INTO current branch isn't always true?

Comment: No, `git merge X` merges **from** `X` **into** the *currently checked out branch*.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm simply interested in the base case of fast-forward merging.

Unfortunately, to really understand this case, you need to start with the hard cases.

> Git fetch downloads data and updates remote tracking branches, but doesn't integrate changes to working tree.

Right.  To understand this more deeply:

- A Git *repository* is, in large part, just two databases.  Both are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), although one is keyed by *names* (branch names, tag names, and other such names) and produces object IDs, and the other one is keyed by object IDs.
- One database contains Git's *objects*.  There are four types of objects, but the main one of interest here is the *commit object*.  A commit object will—indirectly—get you a complete snapshot of every file, as of the form that file had at the time you, or whoever, *made* the commit.  It also gets you the commit's *metadata*, i.e., the information about the commit itself: who made it, when, why (their log message), and so on.
- Each object has its own ID.  The ID *is* the object, in a very real sense: Git can only *find* the object by having its ID, and using that to retrieve the object from that object database.  Some objects—trees, blobs, and so on—can be used multiple times, but every *commit* is required to be unique, and hence to have a unique hash ID.  The uniqueness of commits is enforced by the fact that every commit has a date-and-time-stamp *and*—with a few rare exceptions—the hash ID(s) of some previous commit(s).

When you run `git fetch`, your Git calls up some other Git, which also has these two database.  Your Git queries their name-to-ID database to find their branch names and latest commit hash IDs.  Your Git then checks to see if your object database has the required objects.  If not, your Git has their Git send over any *missing* objects, which your Git can add to your object database.  Now you have all their commits, plus any commits you made that you haven't given to them.

Now that you have all the *commits*, your Git can update your names database.  Here, it takes their *branch* names and turns them into your *remote-tracking* names: e.g., their `refs/heads/main` becomes your `refs/remotes/origin/main`.  It then creates or updates these remote-tracking names, in your names database, with the *same* hash IDs of the commits that their branch names store, in *their* names database.

So, `git fetch` is just a big database update: you get any necessary objects, including new commit objects, and then your Git updates your remote-tracking names.

All objects in the main database are strictly read-only.  No commit or other object can ever change.  (This is enforced in multiple ways: in particular, the hash ID that *finds* the object is a cryptographic checksum of the data *in* the object, so that every Git will compute the *same* hash ID for identical data.  When retrieving an object from the database, Git checks that the key used to *find* the object still matches the checksum of the resulting data.)  So you can only ever *add a new object:* it is literally impossible to change an existing one.

This means all commits are, by nature, read-only, frozen-for-all-time archives of all their files.  To actually *use* a commit requires extracting it from the database; `git fetch` does not do that.

> Git merge will merge the specified branch into the current checked-out branch.

Well ... :-)  The `git merge` command is *complicated*.

> Git pull is a combination of these procedures.

And, again, "well..."  The pull command does indeed run fetch first, then a second Git command, but you can choose *which* second command to use (merge vs rebase) and there are some extra complications here too.  But the *default* is to run `git fetch` first, then `git merge`.  If we ignore the rebase cases, we can get back to merge itself.

> The key idea here which is confusing me is that git merge (alone or as a part of git pull) merges the specified branch *into* the current branch.

It's more accurate to think of `git merge` in terms of *commits*.

A *branch name*, in Git, mostly does one thing: it remembers a commit hash ID.  That's its function in the name-to-hash-ID database, anyway.  (In your `.git/config`, it takes on some extra duties, sort of.)

A *commit*, in Git, acts as both the snapshot-of-all-files (indirectly) *and* as the metadata-holder.  We give Git the commit hash ID, and Git finds the metadata; the metadata include the hash ID of an internal Git *tree* object, and that—in another convoluted manner—finds the snapshot.  For any ordinary commit, however, the commit itself also holds the hash ID of exactly one *previous* commit, which we—and Git—call the *parent* of the commit.

So now we get those diagrams.  Here's a diagram of a small repository with perhaps just eight commits in it.  Each commit has some big ugly hash ID in reality, but we don't want to deal with those, so we have replaced them with single uppercase letters.  The *last* commit in this repository is the eighth, or letter `H`.  We'll write it rightmost here:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Commit `H` stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of earlier commit `G` (plus the tree hash ID that gets us the snapshot for commit `H`).  Given the commit-`G` hash ID, Git can retrieve all of commit `G`: both the snapshot and its metadata.  That gives Git the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on down the line.

So, we just need a way to find the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  That's the only one we *can't* find by following the backwards-looking chain itself.  So that's where the branch name comes in:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

for instance.  Now that we know that the links between commits point backwards—they have to; commit `H` doesn't *exist yet* when commit `G` gets made, and commit `G` can't be updated afterward—we don't bother drawing in the arrows, which lets us move things around:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

is exactly the same drawing, but gives me room to add an arrow pointing to commit `E`, like this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/main
          \
           E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

We'd get *this* diagram if we started by cloning a four-commit repository where `main` was commit `D`, and created our own `main` pointing to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main, origin/main
```

We'd have Git `git checkout main` at this point, extracting the committed files to our working tree so that we can see and work on them (the committed files are stored in a compressed, read-only, Git-only, and *de-duplicated* form with the data being shared across every commit that re-uses some old data, and this stuff has to be *copied out* to ordinary usable computer files, so Git does that).

While I don't really need it here, I'll go ahead and draw in the special name `HEAD`.  This name is normally *attached to* some branch name:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

You literally can't attach `HEAD` to anything that's *not* a branch name, unless you go into *detached HEAD* mode, where `HEAD` points directly to some commit.

In normal mode, Git will read the branch name out of `HEAD`: when `git status` says `on branch main`, that's because `HEAD` holds the name `main`.  Then it will go on to read the commit hash ID from the branch name.  (In fact, you can ask Git to read *just* the name: `git symbolic-ref HEAD` does that.  Using `git rev-parse HEAD` has Git read all the way through to the commit hash ID.  Most Git commands go all the way to the hash ID, internally.)

Anyway, with this as our current situation, we now make one new commit, in the usual way.  Git:

- saves away a full copy of every file, de-duplicating all appropriate files;<sup>1</sup>
- creates new metadata, including your name and email address, and a log message you must supply;
- uses the *current commit* hash ID as the parent for the new commit;
- writes out all this metadata as a new commit, which gains a new, unique hash ID; and ... well, we'll come back to this in a moment.

Let's draw out this new commit `E`.  Because its *parent* is the *current commit* `D`, the new commit points back to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           E
```

I left out the branch and remote-tracking names-and-arrows because of the last step that `git commit` does, which is:

- write the hash ID of the new commit into the current branch name.

So we now have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/main
          \
           E   <-- main (HEAD)
```

All this is happening in *our own repository only*.  The *current branch name* points to the new commit; `HEAD` is still attached to `main`; and the new commit points back to the existing commits.

If we repeat this three more times, we get the picture we drew earlier:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/main
          \
           E--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

If we now run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch` which reads from `origin`), it's very likely that *nothing happens*, because they have no new commits we don't already have.  In that case, our `origin/main` does not move.

If we now ask Git to merge `origin/main` to our current branch `main`, as determined by where `HEAD` is attached, Git:

- locates commit `H`: that's our current commit;
- locates commit `D`: that's where `origin/main` points;
- uses the *graph* we've been drawing to find the *merge base*.

This is our first, and perhaps most important, complication.

---

<sup>1</sup>The de-duplication is actually done in advance.  When you modify a working tree file, one of the reasons you have to run `git add` on it is so that Git can de-duplicate it right then.  This updates a cache of the files Git will put in the *next* commit.  This cache is called, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely now—the *cache*.

---

#### Merge bases

Merge bases determine a lot of the behavior of the `git merge` command.

Remember that we're always working with the *current branch*, i.e., the one to which `HEAD` is attached.  If we only have one *branch* name, there's only one possible place for `HEAD` to be attached.  (We could be in *detached HEAD* mode, but let's ignore this.  In fact it doesn't really change very much though.)  If we have multiple branch names, `HEAD` selects the right one.  Then that name selects the right commit.  So that's one of *three* commits that are inputs to a merge.  Internally, however, the merge operation calls this commit #2.

All merge operations involve some other (often "remote" or "other branch") commit.  We name *which commit that is* on our `git merge` command line.  If we run `git merge` with no option at all, the commit we're asking to use here is the one from the current branch's *upstream* setting, which we haven't described; and if we use `git pull`, the `git pull` command actually supplies the raw hash ID directly.  In all cases, this is, internally, commit #3.

So: what is commit #1?  That's the *merge base*.  Git finds the merge base for us, and in fact, won't let us specify the merge base at all.<sup>2</sup>  The way Git *finds* the merge base is to use the *commit graph*.

The drawings you made above, and the one I have so far, just have a simple case of "strictly ahead" or "strictly behind".  These are actually *easy* cases for `git merge`.  The *hard* case occurs when we have something like this:

```
          I--J   <-- main
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
```

Here, the *merge base* is commit `H`.  At some point, when we were in sync with `origin/main`, we were both *at* commit `H`.  Since then, we've added two commits—`I` and `J`—and they added two commits as well, which we will call `K` and `L`.  The merge command *finds* the merge base using some fancy graph algorithms,<sup>3</sup> but you can think of it as *the best shared commit*.  In some drawings—like this one—it's really easy to see which commit that is.

This merge base commit, here `H`, is commit #1, for one of these standard `git merge` operations.  So Git finds these three commits, and their hash IDs and their relative positions in the graph: #1 is the base, #2 is `--ours` (or `HEAD`), and #3 is `--theirs` (or the one you supplied with your `git merge` command line).

---

<sup>2</sup>If you reach down into some of Git's internals, it *is* possible to specify the merge base directly.  The `cherry-pick` and `revert` commands are also implemented using the merge machinery, and they pick a carefully contrived merge base.  But we'll ignore all that here too.

<sup>3</sup>See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs for a gentle introduction to Lowest Common Ancestor of a DAG.  There can be more than one; we aren't going to cover that case here.

---

#### Now we can consider the various easy cases

Git is always going to find these three hash IDs.  For the *hard* case, we get one like the drawing above: commit #1, the base, is `H` and the other two are two more commits.  This kind of merge requires some real work.

We want the easy cases, though.  Those occur when the merge base—the best shared ancestor commit—is either the *current commit*, `HEAD`, or is the *other commit*.

Let's go back to this case:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/main
          \
           E--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

If we run `git merge origin/main`, Git has to find commit `D`, then has to find the best *shared* commit.  To do that, Git works backwards from `H` and also works backwards from `D`.  We can see, immediately, that if we go four steps back from `H`, we land at `D`, and if we go zero steps backwards from `D` we stay at `D`.  So commit `D` *is* the merge base.

Since commit `D` is the merge base, though, and it's *behind* `H`, there is simply *nothing to do*.  Git says: `Already up to date.`  The merge command stops there, having done nothing at all.

We could, of course, find ourselves in the opposite situation.  Suppose we clone some repository and wind up with:

```
...--D   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

Then, after a few seconds go by (the `origin` repository has fast committers), we run `git fetch` and find that we now have:

```
...--D   <-- main (HEAD)
      \
       E--F--G--H   <-- origin/main
```

We run `git merge origin/main`.  Git locates commits `D` and `H` as before, and finds that the merge base is commit `D` as before.  But this time `D` is *behind* the other commit.

Git *could* do a full-blown three-way merge.  We have not described in detail how this works, but if Git *did* do this, the result would look like this:

```
...--D------------I   <-- main (HEAD)
      \          /
       E--F--G--H   <-- origin/main
```

where new commit `I` is a *merge commit*.  If we had described the full merge, we would have noted how Git has to compare (as with `git diff`) the merge base against each of the two branch-tip commits.  Git would thus be comparing commit `D` with itself—commit `D`—and would find *no changes*.  The result of combining *no changes* with *some other changes* matches the snapshot in commit `H`, so if we had Git perform this full merge, new commit `I` would use the same snapshot as existing commit `H`.  It would, however, have all new metadata.

**The fast-forward operation that Git uses by default here is not a merge.**  Instead, Git notices that merge base `D` and current commit `D` are *the same commit*, and that the result of a real merge would be the snapshot in `H`.  If you then *allow or require it*, `git merge` will do a fast-forward operation *instead of* a true merge.  A fast-forward "merge" is basically just a `git checkout`, except that it drags the branch name forward with it:

```
...--D
      \
       E--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

and now there's no reason to draw the kink in the graph:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

So *no existing commits change* (that's not possible anyway), and importantly, no *new merge commit gets added either*.  Instead, the current branch—as found by the special name `HEAD`—just gets dragged forwards, in the opposite direction that the internal connecting arrows point.

#### Conclusion

A fast-forward merge is a special case where a branch name "moves forward" and we check out the target commit.  We *pick* the target commit by passing a commit hash ID, or something Git can turn into a hash ID, to `git merge`.  We get the fast-forward action if:

- no merge is required; and
- no merge is forced (`--no-ff` forces a real merge); and
- fast-forward is allowed (the default) or required (`--ff-only` causes the merge to fail if a real merge is required).

I kind of wish that Git did not call this a merge, because it isn't one.  It does, however, result in a different *checkout:* now instead of being on commit `D`, we're on commit `H`.

Git has other fast-forward operations, where it moves a branch name forward like this, without any checking-out occurring.  These are used with `git push`, for instance; and `git fetch` will distinguish between a non-forced update, such as going from:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
```

to:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- origin/main
```

vs a forced update that *drops* a commit, such as going to:

```
       H
      /
...--G   <-- origin/main
```

(Note that commit `H` sticks around in your repository for at least a little while, and if you can find it, you can still see it.  If you have *your own* branch name, such as `main`, pointing to commit `H`, or a commit that leads backwards to `H`, commit `H` remains very easy to find.  If not, Git has things called *reflogs* that make it possible to find commit `H` for some time.  As long as something still finds it, the commit can't go away; once *no name* finds it, the commit is eligible for "garbage collection", but you can still view it by raw hash ID—if you have it memorized, or written down, or something—until `git gc` really does take it out.)

These *forced updates* use the `--force` flag, or the special `+` annotation on a *refspec* (which is another topic entirely).  A non-forced-update is the kind of update that Git "likes": it just *adds new commits*, a process that Git is built to do and happy to execute.  A forced update can throw a commit out, like the example with commit `H` above being tossed off `origin/main`.